# Python Turtle : Sorting Visualiser - Issue with Inserion Sort algorithm Visualisation

Tags: python, algorithm, turtle-graphics, python-turtle, insertion-sort

```
# Insertion Sort
def ins_sort():
    for i in range(1, len(l)):
        key = l[i]
        key_turtle = a[i]
        key_turtle.color("red")
        j = i - 1
        while j >= 0 and key < l[j]:
            a[j].color("yellow")
            a[j].setx(a[j + 1].xcor())
            a[j + 1] = a[j]
            l[j + 1] = l[j]
            j -= 1
            # wn.update()
        key_turtle.setx(a[j + 1].xcor())
        a[j + 1] = key_turtle
        l[j + 1] = key
        a[j + 1].color("green")
        wn.update()
```

This function ins_sort() is supposed to sort the lines(Turtle Objects) in ascending order.
To achieve this, 3 things need to be done :-

1. Sort array of turtle objects - stored in list 'a'
2. Sort array of their lengths(according to which sorting is done) - stored in list 'l'
3. Move the lines to their correct sorted positions on the screen(Visualization)

The main **issue with the ins_sort()** function is that **it doesn't move the lines to their correct positions**. Even though **it does sort the lists 'a' and 'l'**, **the only problem is with the movement(Visualisation).**

I've tried nearly everything, from ChatGPT to documentations but no help.
I do think the code is correct and their maybe some issue with the Turtle module or some built-in functions.

Here is the complete code for reference :-
(You may remove the color lines for better readability)

```
import turtle
import random
import time

# Screen
wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.title("Sorting Visualiser")
wn.setup(width=1200, height=700)
wn.tracer(0)


# Background
def display_vis():
    dispbg = turtle.Turtle()
    dispbg.color("grey")
    dispbg.fillcolor("#DAECFF")
    dispbg.speed(0)
    dispbg.hideturtle()
    dispbg.penup()
    dispbg.width(4)
    dispbg.goto(-412.5, 266)
    dispbg.pendown()
    dispbg.begin_fill()
    for i in range(2):
        dispbg.forward(831.5)
        dispbg.right(90)
        dispbg.forward(569)
        dispbg.right(90)
    dispbg.end_fill()
    wn.update()


# Initialization
a = []
l = []
d = 8
pen = [0] * 4
writer = [0] * 4

write_time = turtle.Turtle()
write_time.hideturtle()

# Hiding Turtle
def hide_turtle():
    for i in range(4):
        pen[i].reset()
        pen[i].hideturtle()
        writer[i].reset()
        writer[i].hideturtle()
    wn.update()


# Showing Turtle
def show_turtle():
    function_button()


# Generating Lines
def generate_lines():
    global d, a, l
    for _ in range(100):
        line = turtle.Turtle()
        line.hideturtle()
        line.shape("square")
        line.color("cyan")
        alen = random.uniform(0.1, 28)
        line.shapesize(stretch_len=alen, stretch_wid=0.2)
        l.append(alen)
        line.speed(0)
        line.left(90)
        line.penup()
        res_len_sel = 300 - (alen * 10)
        line.goto((-400 + d), -res_len_sel)
        line.showturtle()
        a.append(line)
        d += 8
    d = 8
    wn.update()

# Selection Sort
def sel_sort():
    for i in range(100):
        a[i].color("#FF1100")
        var = a[i].xcor()
        length = l[i]
        pos = i

        for j in range(i + 1, 100):
            if l[j] < length:
                length = l[j]
                var = a[j].xcor()
                pos = j
            a[j].color("cyan")

        a[pos].color("green")
        a[pos].setx(a[i].xcor())
        a[i].setx(var)
        a[i], a[pos] = a[pos], a[i]
        l[i], l[pos] = l[pos], l[i]
        wn.update()

# Bubble Sort
def bub_sort():
    for i in range(99):
        for j in range(99 - i):
            var = a[j].xcor()
            vara = a[j + 1].xcor()
            if l[j] > l[j + 1]:
                a[j].setx(vara)
                a[j + 1].setx(var)
                a[j], a[j + 1] = a[j + 1], a[j]
                l[j], l[j + 1] = l[j + 1], l[j]
                a[j].color("cyan")
            a[j + 1].color("green")
        wn.update()
    a[0].color("green")
    wn.update()

# Insertion Sort
def ins_sort():
    for i in range(1, len(l)):
        key = l[i]
        key_turtle = a[i]
        key_turtle.color("red")
        j = i - 1
        while j >= 0 and key < l[j]:
            a[j].color("yellow")
            a[j].setx(a[j + 1].xcor())
            a[j + 1] = a[j]
            l[j + 1] = l[j]
            j -= 1
            # wn.update()
        key_turtle.setx(a[j + 1].xcor())
        a[j + 1] = key_turtle
        l[j + 1] = key
        a[j + 1].color("green")
        wn.update()

# Clearing Screen
def clear_screen():
    global a, l
    for line in a:
        line.clear()
        line.hideturtle()
    del a[:]
    del l[:]
    generate_lines()

# Generating Buttons
def generate_buttons(x, y, obj, msg):
    pen[obj] = turtle.Turtle()
    pen[obj].hideturtle()
    pen[obj].penup()
    pen[obj].goto(x - 80, y - 20)
    pen[obj].pendown()
    pen[obj].color("#52A1FA")
    pen[obj].begin_fill()
    for i in range(2):
        pen[obj].fd(160)
        pen[obj].left(90)
        pen[obj].fd(40)
        pen[obj].left(90)
    pen[obj].end_fill()
    writer[obj] = turtle.Turtle()
    writer[obj].hideturtle()
    writer[obj].penup()
    writer[obj].goto(x, y - 7.5)
    writer[obj].write(msg, font=('Verdana', 12, 'normal'), align="center")
    wn.update()

# Generating Buttons
def function_button():
    generate_buttons(-300, 300, 0, "Create New Lines")
    generate_buttons(-100, 300, 1, "Selection Sort")
    generate_buttons(100, 300, 2, "Bubble Sort")
    generate_buttons(300, 300, 3, "Insertion Sort")

# Time Taken
def write_timeTaken(t):
    global write_time
    write_time.hideturtle()
    write_time.penup()
    write_time.goto(0, -325)
    write_time.write("Time Taken: " + str(t), font=('Verdana', 12, 'normal'), align="center")
    wn.update()

# Checking Screen Click
def checki(x, y):
    write_time.clear()
    if x > (-380) and x < (-220) and y > 280 and y < 320:
        hide_turtle()
        clear_screen()
        show_turtle()
    elif x > (-180) and x < (-20) and y > 280 and y < 320:
        hide_turtle()
        t1 = time.time()
        sel_sort()
        t2 = time.time()
        write_timeTaken(t2 - t1)
        show_turtle()
    elif x > 20 and x < 180 and y > 280 and y < 320:
        hide_turtle()
        t1 = time.time()
        bub_sort()
        t2 = time.time()
        write_timeTaken(t2 - t1)
        show_turtle()
    elif x > 220 and x < 380 and y > 280 and y < 320:
        hide_turtle()
        t1 = time.time()
        ins_sort()
        t2 = time.time()
        write_timeTaken(t2 - t1)
        show_turtle()

# Screen
display_vis()

# Generating Buttons
function_button()
turtle.onscreenclick(checki)
turtle.listen()

turtle.done()
```

Comment: It's unclear. Elaborate what is the incorrect behavior and what is expected.

Comment: @relent95 The problem is with the visualisation part, wherein the drawn lines are supposed to move to their sorted positions, however it doesn't happen, various errors in this. However, the lists do get sorted accordingly but it doesn't reflect on the screen.

Comment: My bad. Yesterday I clicked the selection sort button and thought it works good. Check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the original x coordinates of turtle objects in the list `a` be `xcors` before calling the `ins_sort()`. Inside the loop in the function, when you call the `a[j + 1].xcor()`, the result may not be equal to the `xcors[j + 1]`, because you keep changing the x coordinates of turtle objects.

One way of solving this problem is using a backup of x coordinates like this.

```
def ins_sort():
    xcors = [t.xcor() for t in a]
    for i in range(1, len(l)):
        ...
        while j >= 0 and key < l[j]:
            ...
            a[j].setx(xcors[j + 1])
            a[j + 1] = a[j]
            ...
        key_turtle.setx(xcors[j + 1])
        a[j + 1] = key_turtle
        ...
```

Comment: This works, thanks.
However, I don't understand why does 'a[j + 1].xcor()' create an issue.

Comment: @MdAafaque Print ```a[j + 1].xcor()``` and ```xcors[j + 1]``` values inside the loop. Compare and analyze them, then you will see.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [Wikipedia insertion sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort) page, here's a simplified function without line coloring that should do what you want:

```
def ins_sort():
    for i in range(len(l)):

        j = i

        while j > 0 and l[j - 1] > l[j]:
            xcor = a[j - 1].xcor()
            a[j - 1].setx(a[j].xcor())
            a[j].setx(xcor)

            l[j - 1], l[j] = l[j], l[j - 1]
            a[j - 1], a[j] = a[j], a[j - 1]

            j -= 1
            # wn.update()

        wn.update()
```

You should be able to add back your visualizations.

Comment: This works, thanks a lot.
However is this really insertion sort, as the elements are swapping rather than shifting and then inserting a key element.